# Different MD5 SUM on the same JAR on different systems

Tags: java, linux, maven, jakarta-ee, jar

So I have a JAVAEE application which use a lot of libraires (JAR files), and all of them are put into an WAR which is also put into an EAR. I have two EAR, which are almost identical and contain the exact same version of another library but when deployed on two different systems (both GNU/Linux, 3.0.93 and 3.0.74) the same JAR doesn't have the same sum MD5 (using "md5sum -b lib.jar" on the two systems). Also, this JAR is on a maven repository and the MD5 sum of the JAR on the maven repository is also different than the two others (as retrieve from the lib.jar.md5 file).

How can I explain that ? The sum MD5 shouldn't be the same ?

Comment: "Almost identical" should not result in the same MD5 sum. That's the whole point...

Comment: I'm wondering: does that jar have the same size when you `ls -l` it on the two systems?

Comment: Yes, the EAR are not identical, but the JAR contained inside are identical.

Comment: They have the exact same size using ls on the two systems 147118o but on the repository it size is 146521o.

Comment: Are the jars built by the build process?

Comment: No, we are using the released version that is downloaded from the company maven repository (and the two EAR were build on TeamCity a continuous integration server).

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope can you get both files on the same system and `cmp` them or diff a hexdump? If they differ on bytes 11-14 it's a different timestamp on potentially identical files.

Comment: Using an HEX editor I realised that the JAR are actually differents. The order in which properties appear in the MANIFEST.MF file is different and the one that was deployed on WAS8.0 have a web-fragment_merged.xml in the META-INF directory. Could this be Websphere that does that ?